# How do I calculate the sum efficiently?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization

Given an integer `n` such that `(1<=n<=10^18)`

We need to calculate `f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+f(4)+....+f(n)`.

`f(x)` is given as :-

Say, `x = 1112222333`, 
then `f(x)=1002000300`.

Whenever we see a contiguous subsequence of same numbers, we replace it with the first number and zeroes all behind it.

Formally, `f(x) = Sum over all (first element of the contiguous subsequence * 10^i )`, where `i` is the index of first element from left of a particular contiguous subsequence.

`f(x)=1*10^9 + 2*10^6 + 3*10^2 = 1002000300`.

In, x=1112222333, 
Element at index '9':-1 
and so on...

We follow zero based indexing :-)

For, x=1234. 
Element at index-'0':-4,element at index -'1':3,element at index '2':-2,element at index 3:-1

How to calculate `f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+....+f(n)`?

I want to generate an algorithm which calculates this sum efficiently.

Comment: Is this a hackerrank task?

Comment: Can you explain how `Sum over all (i * 10^i )` leads to `1*10^9 + 2*10^6 + 3*10^2`?

Comment: For x=1112222333,the contiguous parts are:-(111) and (2222) and (333). So, sum=1*(10^left-most index of (111) ) +2*(10^leftmost-index of (2222))+3*...and so on....... (111):Indices are:--->{9,8,7}

Comment: How does `(111)` give `1*10^9`?

Comment: (2222):--->Indices:---->{6,5,4,3)...leftmost-index:6

Comment: (333):-{2,1,0}...indices

Comment: It's a 10-digit number so leftmost index of `(111)` is `10`. Also, `i * 10^i` for `(111)` should then be `10*10^10`, right? or at least, if I understand what you are trying to say, `1 * 10^10`, right?

Comment: I have started indexing from '0'...indexing is like this:- 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 : 1112222333

Comment: Updated the question :-)

Comment: Just to poke at this Q a little:  would `22111331143` equal `2*10^10 + 1*10^8 + 3*10^5 +1*10^3 + 4*10^1 +3*10^0` ? We can have 19 indicies, or 10^18 indicies?

Comment: I have used x for explanation purposes

Comment: f(1)=1 and f(2)=2. I have explained everything in the question... All we have to do is calculate those values efficiently.

Comment: @anayaAgarwal I was confised initially I thoight you may have bbeen using 10^18 to tell the number of indices.

Comment: My tought is that you actually have very static multiplicatives here you know all of the base values, so there is no need to use the 10^i notation except dor writing, all of those are static values.

Comment: So you have 19 static values in an array, and all you have to do is substitute the value of the index.  In fact you don't need to do any real calculations at all, rhis can be dome with string manip and that may or may not be faster

Comment: In fact, there is no calculation at all, this seems a trick question.

Comment: Oh, did I miss something? How would you do that without a calculation?

Comment: This is an ongoing contest problem: codechef august long challenge division 2

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: thank you for the info. The original poster obviouly didn't like to reveal this info. Taking help is ok, revealing info maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

To approach this problem, it could help to begin with one digit numbers and see what sum you get. 
I mean like this:

Let's say, we define [image: <code>F(k)=\sum_{x=1}^{10^k-1} f(x)</code> (click for the rendered version)], then we have:

```
F(1)= 45                # =10*9/2 by Euler's sum formula
F(2)= F(1)*9 + F(1)*100 # F(1)*9 is the part that comes from the last digit
                        # because for each of the 10 possible digits in the
                        # first position, we have 9 digits in the last 
                        # because both can't be equal and so one out of ten
                        # becomse zero. F(1)*100 comes from the leading digit 
                        # which is multiplied by 100 (10 because we add the
                        # second digit and another factor of 10 because we 
                        # get the digit ten times in that position)
```

If you now continue with this scheme, for `k>=1` in general you get

```
F(k+1)= F(k)*100+10^(k-1)*45*9
```

The rest is probably straightforward.

Can you tell me, which Hackerrank task this is? I guess one of the Project Euler tasks right?

Comment: I guess you misunderstood...f(1)=1 and f(2)=2.

Comment: I have updated the question....f(6)=6*(10^0)=6,where '0' is the index of '6'. If it was 61, f(61)=60=6*(10^1)+1*(10^0)=61...and f(66)=60.

Comment: No I think I didn't misunderstand you. `F(k)` is just a partial result, from which it should be possible to calculate your sum easily. Also in math divide and conquer is a good strategy at times. But how about my question? If I spent time answering your question, would you tell me, where you have this question from?

Comment: This will still give TLE as `n` can take values upto `10^18` and you are calculating `F(x)` for every `x` in range `[1, n]`.

Comment: No, I don't. I dervived how the sum can be calculated without using the whole loop. What is TLE btw?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to calculate.

Multiplying each position in the array od numbers will yeild thebsame number.

So all you want to do is end up with 0s on a repeated number

IE lets populate  some static values in an array in psuedo code

````
$As[1]='0'
$As[2]='00'
$As[3]='000' 
...etc 
$As[18]='000000000000000000'```

these are the "results" of 10^index

Given a value n of `1234`

```1&000 + 2&00 +3 & 0 + 4```

Results in `1234`

So, if you are putting this on a chip, then probably your most efficient method is to do a bitwise XOR between each register and the next up the line as a single operation

Then you will have 0s in all the spots you care about, and just retrive the values in the registers with a 1


In code, I think it would be most efficient to do the following

```$n = arbitrary value 11223334
$x=$n*10
$zeros=($x-$n)/10```



Okay yeah we can just do bit shifting to get a value like 100200300400 etc.
````